# Using Json when there are multiple similar data sets

Tags: java, json

New-ish to Java and just discovered the wonders of JSON.

I have my game API (https://rsbuddy.com/exchange/summary.json)

This lists all the items for sale in the game.

Using JSON and by entering a specific item ID I have got my code to return all relevant buying/ selling data for that item. Simple

TLDR

Now it's getting more complicated than my coding ability as I want to create a method that subtracts the buying data of an item from the selling data of that same item thus allowing me to discover the true margins of every item in one foul swoop, and ideally return them with the largest margin item at the top of the list.

Any guidance on how I might achieve this would be apreciated!

Comment: Are you sure you're using Java and not javascript? Just seems unlikely that you'd be new to Java and JSON and yet be thinking in terms of json...

Comment: Hey, yes I am programming with Java in IntelliJ IDEA. Json is what I need to use to parse the data i'm collecting. Could you advise how i can share parts of my code here like the chap that commented before you?

Comment: JSON is a data storage format. Use Jackson to parse it. Load it into a map and then do whatever you need with it

Comment: Yeah got ya. I don't know anything about loading into a map yet so i need to look into that. I only just discovered JSON the other day but thanks for the guidance I'm looking in the right direction now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `json` in the example has many elements like the one below:

```
"2": {
        "overall_average": 197,
        "buy_average": 197,
        "id": 2,
        "sp": 5,
        "sell_average": 197,
        "members": true,
        "name": "Cannonball"
    }
```

You can define a model that can be used to serialize-deserialize the part containing `overall_average` etc. Below is an example (using `jasckson`):

```
class Element {
    @JsonProperty("overall_average")
    private int overallAverage;

    @JsonProperty("buy_average")
    private int buyAverage;

    //Other properties and getters-setters
}
```

Once this is done, you can wrap it into `Map`, it would look like this:

```
Map<String, Element> data;
```

Using the above model, you can deserialise the json into `Map` and use `map.get` to get the item by id:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String,Element> data = mapper.readValue("<json>", new TypeReference<Map<String,Element>>() {});
```

[Here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs)'s the documentation for Jackson.

Comment: Great, thanks @DarshanMehta Jackson is just what I was after. Reading about that now